# Trello search and filter by due date

Tags: trello

Is is possible to search and filter by due date? For example, cards due this week, cards due today, overdue cards.

It does not look like it, and I can't see a card on the Trello Development Board requesting such a feature.

As a team leader or project manager it's important to keep abreast of committed work for member allocation and work scheduling.

Comment: It would be very useful to be able to search for cards *without* a due date.  I haven't found any syntax that lets me do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Trello Calendar](https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/).

It shows all your cards from all your boards. You also have an ICS feed to integrate it with Google Calendar or others.

Answer (score 1):

See also Trello Powerup Calendar Feature: http://blog.trello.com/introducing-power-ups-calendar-card-aging-and-more/

You can also use Ultimello Chrome Extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm to sort cards by due date in a list.

Answer (score 1):

This is [now possible](http://blog.trello.com/card-filter-updates-cards-page-sorting-checklist-copy-and-more/). From the sidebar of your board, click *Menu* → *Filter Cards* then choose one of the options:

> - Due in the next day
> - Due in the next week
> - Due in the next month
> - Overdue

This will only filter on the current board, but this seems to be exactly what you asked for.